# Комбинация слова и символа: когда пишется слитно, а когда раздельно?

Tags: лексика, слитно-раздельно, оформление-текста, редактура, знак

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какому правилу следовать при комбинации слов со знаками, нужно ли разделять их пробелом или писать слитно? Например, как быть со знаком + (плюс): нужно ли писать его слитно со словом, если знак относится только к одному слову (вышка 4G+, картель ОПЕК+, БАД "Видрум+"), и раздельно, если относится к словосочетанию (БАД "Видрум Форте +")?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО (30.11.2022)**

"Грамота.ру" наконец ответила (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=310108)):

> Такие написания не регламентируются правилами орфографии. Предложенный Вами принцип представляется удачным.

Comment: + (плюс) является математическим символом, его место в формулах.

Comment: Это понятно, но в практике письма ведь появляются такие химеры (видимо, из английского с тем же 4G+)...